I'm looking for a word for doing something because you know it is the better choice even though you don't want to
In my head, I associate the word with reluctantly and being the bigger person.
An example where the word would be appropriate to use is: I let the little kid play with my phone even though I saw him put his fingers in his mouth, and I am a slight germaphobe because, in my heart, I know it is the better decision to let the kid do their thing than follow my selfish wants and take my phone away, causing the kid to create a scene making everything more difficult.
The word isn't like capitulate because I am not conceding to someone's demands. It is more along the lines of doing something (generally for the greater good) even though I do not want to, but by my own choice. It is like feeling reluctant but having agency in the choice made.
I forgot to add, but this theoretical word in my head isn't too negative. I mentioned it before, but I think capitulate has slightly too much of a negative and forceful connotation.

For word requests, please edit to give a sample sentence showing how the word would be used. I think the best choice here is simply to pair "reluctantly" with the appropriate verb.

Not exactly the same but word for having the strength to do the right thing, doing something because you can't easily refuse, doing something you don't want to do, etc.

Your approach could be called pragmatic. Per Collins Dictionary:

A pragmatic way of dealing with something is based on practical considerations, rather than theoretical ones. A pragmatic person deals with things in a practical way.

Robin took a pragmatic look at her situation.

Perhaps "concede" or "tolerate" would do the job.
M-W gives for concede:

1
a
(1)
: to acknowledge grudgingly or hesitantly
conceded that it might be a good idea

(2)
: to relinquish grudgingly or hesitantly
concede power
b
: to accept as true, valid, or accurate
The right of the state to tax is generally conceded.
2
: to grant as a right or privilege
Britain conceded the independence of the colonies.


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
